# Table appears in Visual mode of editor but not in preview or after publish

Tags: plugins, table

I'm using [compare](http://demo.awesem.com/?theme=compare) theme and I am facing a problem with the `tables`. I have created a HTML table, which when I go to Visual mode appears to be correct.

[image]

But when I preview/publish it then I don't see the table. You can check it [here](http://laptopoffer.info/product/notebooks/hp/hp-pavilion-g4-1311tu/). Only the text of cells is there.

Below is the part of code of `single-product.php` file which generates the page.

```
<div class="comparison-text">
                <h1 class="title"><?php echo stripslashes(get_the_title()); ?></h1>
                <?php

                // Check if has global product description ( also stored as post meta )             
                $q = "SELECT product_description FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."pc_products_custom WHERE product_id = ".$post->ID;   
                $result = $wpdb->get_results($q);
                $content = $result[0]->product_description;

                // If no global product description use default one.

                if ($content == ''){
                    $q = "SELECT rel.id_feed, rel.id_product FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."pc_products_feeds_relationships rel JOIN ".$wpdb->prefix."pc_feeds fe ON rel.id_feed = fe.id WHERE rel.id_product = ".$merchants[0]->id_product." AND fe.feed_use_master_description = 1 AND fe.active = 1 LIMIT 1";
                    $results_f = $wpdb->get_row($q);
                    $results_desc;
                    if(!empty($results_f)){     
                        $q = "SELECT slug FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."pc_products_merchants WHERE feed = ".$results_f->id_feed;
                        $results_s = $wpdb->get_row($q);

                        $q = "SELECT feed_product_desc FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."pc_products WHERE id_product = ".$results_f->id_product." AND id_merchant='".$results_s->slug."' LIMIT 1";
                        $results_desc = $wpdb->get_row($q);

                    }   
                    if (!empty($results_desc->feed_product_desc)){
                        $content = $results_desc->feed_product_desc;
                    } else {                
                        $content = get_the_content();
                        $content = strip_tags($content);
                    }
                }

                $size = 3500;
                if(strlen($content) > $size) {
                    while(isset($content[$size]) && $content[$size] != ' ') {
                        $size++;
                    }
                    $display_content  = substr($content,0,$size).'<span class="desc_more" style="display:none;">'.substr($content,$size,strlen($content)).'</span><span class="desc_etc">...</span> <a href="#" id="more_link" onclick="more(); return false;">'.__('More','framework').'</a>';
                    $display_content .= '';
                } else {
                    $display_content = $content;
                }
                ?>
                <?php echo $display_content; ?>

            <!-- END .comparison-text -->
```

I don't know PHP but I guess that `$display_content` is skipping the table. Does anybody know the reason of this issue and how can this be solved? I tried the `Easy-Table` and `Tablepress` plugins but they also didn't work.

Comment: If you copy and paste your table HTML code in text mode and then have a look at the draft, do you still get the same results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever `$results_desc->feed_product_desc` is empty, the post content is used. Otherwise the content is never used.

```
if (!empty($results_desc->feed_product_desc)){
    $content = $results_desc->feed_product_desc;
} else {
    $content = get_the_content();
    $content = strip_tags($content);
}
```

Whenever the post content is used, all HTML tags are stripped.

```
$content = get_the_content();
$content = strip_tags($content);
```

To get the full content with all the tags, use just the first line:

```
$content = get_the_content();
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that line. One should be patient while debugging. :)

Comment: Bugs never arrive when you are patient. They arrive only when they know you are tired and sleepy. :)